Are my two versions of proofs correct regarding how we can achieve perfect secrecy even with a relaxed correctness condition?
Typically when talking about perfect secrecy in the context of private-key encryption schemes we impose the requirement of correctness which says $P[D(k,E(k,m))=m] = 1$. In other words, using the same key $k$ to decrypt a ciphertext $c$ which is the encryption of a message $m$ using the same key, will always yield the original message. This makes a lot of sense as this avoids any ambiguity during decryption regarding what original message produced the given ciphertext.
Suppose we relax the encryption correctness property so that $\forall m \in M$ and any $t \geq 1$,
$$
P[D(k, E(k, m)) = m] \geq \frac{1}{2^t}.
$$
I want to show that in this scenario, perfect secrecy can be achieved with $|K| \leq |M|$.

We want to show that
$$
P[E(k, m_{0}) \rightarrow c\ ] = P[E(k, m_{1}) \rightarrow c\ ],\ \forall m_{0}, m_{1} \in M.
$$
I claim that the probability of the key $k$ and the message $m$ producing the ciphertext $c$ is equal to the probability of picking said key. Namely, $P[E(k,m) \rightarrow c\ ] = P[k=k_{i}]$. If we have $|K| \geq |M|$, then we can have a unique key per message and thus $P[k=k_{i}]=\frac{1}{|K|}$. However, given our relaxed condition $|K| \leq |M|$, some messages must now share a key and as such the probability of drawing a given key has changed.
If we construct our key distribution in such a way that we map each $k \in K$ to exactly $2^{t}$ messages, then $P[k=k_{i}] = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|}$. In practice, this way of distributing the keys means that all the messages $m$ have an equal probability to produce the ciphertext $c$. It is important to note that his holds since the distribution of keys does not favor any particular message, perfect secrecy is preserved.
$$
P[E(k, m_{0}) \rightarrow c\ ] = P[E(k, m_{1}) \rightarrow c\ ] = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|},\ \forall m_{0}, m_{1} \in M.
$$
Q.E.D.

I believe the more "general"/"typical" way of going about proving this would be to prove that $P[C=c|M=m]=P[M=m]$ applying Bayes theorem on the LHS. Let's try that.
$$
P[M=m|C=c] = \frac{P[C=c|M=m]P[M=m]}{P[C=c]} = P[M=m].
$$
We know that $P[M=m|C=c] = P[E(k,m) \rightarrow c] = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|}$ and $P[M=m]=\frac{1}{|M|}$. For the equality to hold it must be true that $P[C=c|M=m] = P[C=c]$. Thus, we must show that the marginal probability $P[C=c] = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|}$.
$$
P[C=c] = \sum_{m \in M} P[C=c|M=m']P[M=m'] = \sum_{m \in M} \frac{2^{t}}{|M|} \frac{1}{|M|} = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|} \sum_{m \in M} \frac{1}{|M|} = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|} \cdot 1 = \frac{2^{t}}{|M|} = P[C=c|M=m].
$$

There is no direct problem with the way you approached with proofs except that whether such a scheme exists also needs to be shown, to stop the proofs being vacuous.
You are in effect "overloading" this scheme so that each key maps to $\geq 2^t$ messages. This is more reminiscent of an authentication or keyed hash system.
It would be nice to have an equidistribution property, meaning that you modify your probability requirement to be
$$
P[D(k, E(k, m)) = m] = \frac{1}{2^t},
$$
for all keys and messages. So each key should map to exactly $2^m$ messages, otherwise you have some information leak in the system.
This would then mean that you would want to take $|M|=2^t |K|.$ But is this possible?
There is an area of mathematics studying such structures, called design theory. What you want is a $t-$design (standard terminology, not your $t$) which is a block design with $t=1.$

The simplest type of "balanced" design ($t=1$) is known as a tactical configuration or $1-$design. Each block contains $k$ elements and each element is contained in $r$ blocks. The number of set elements $v$ and the number of blocks $b$ are related by
$$bk=vr$$
which is the total number of element occurrences.

Take the messages to be the blocks. Then the number of messages $|M|=b.$ You want the number of keys (elements) to be $v=|K|=b2^{t_0}$ (your $t$ is now $t_0$).

Every binary matrix with constant row and column sums is the incidence matrix of a regular uniform block design.

Given $m$ messages and $k$ keys, we can form the $k\times m$ incidence matrix $C(m,k)$ with exactly $m$ one's in its first row (if $C(i,j)=1$ this means key $j$ is associated with message $i$) thus in all its rows) to obtain a design representing this requirement. For example, $m=4,k=8$ would possibly give (actually you can see the 1's need not be consecutive as long as there is $m$ of them):
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
11110000 \\
01111000 \\
00111100 \\
00011110 \\
00001111 \\
10000111 \\
11000011\\
11100001\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
where the rows are indexed by messages and the columns by keys.
